# Designer Permission Group View

Tags: 2013, javascript, permissions, jquery

I am working in SharePoint 2013 and I working on a page that has a custom feature on it.  The look and feel of the custom feature looks fine as long as the person or persons is placed into the designer permission group on the page or site collection.  If they are no in the designer group the custom feature looks distorted.  I do not want to put viewers into the designer group.

Do you know why this happening like this?  Is there way I can give viewers something similar to designer permission group but without the full access?

Comment: In addition to Mike's answer, you may need to check that users have access (Read access?) to the Style Library.  In my SP 2013 deployment custom scripts, like Javascript, are located in the Style Library, though in your system they could be in a different Library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't give the viewers the "designer" permission. Does the "custom feature" reference a CSS or JavaScript file? If so, check to see:

- if the viewers have at least read permissions on the file
- if the file is checked in
- if the Publishing features are enabled, the file has been published.

Comment: Checked all suggestions.  Everything checked out.  Is there something more that I am missing?

Comment: Can't think of anything else. It really sounds like a permissions issue on CSS file or an image file.